# Why does $k^2+4k+4$ become $(k+2)^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm studying maths after a lot of years without having a look at it.

Currently I'm doing proof by induction, I have a doubt when doing an exercise.

If you have a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ANcEiSPsqDk&t=315) at minute 5:15 , $[k^2+4k+4]$ becomes $(k+2)^2$ and I don't understand why.

Is there any rule or theorem that explains this?

Comment: $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$

Comment: BTW if you want to link to specific time in a youtube video, you can do it like this: https://youtu.be/ANcEiSPsqDk?list=WL&t=315 See also:[Linking directly to a specific point in time of a YouTube video](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/732/linking-directly-to-a-specific-point-in-time-of-a-youtube-video) at webapps.SE.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

depending on the area of rectangle

[image]

$$k^2+2k+2k+4=(k+2)(k+2)$$
$$(k^2+4k+4)=(k+2)^2$$

Comment: I have never seen this before, but it is a very neat way of solving this kind of problem (+1)

Answer (score 4):

The general rule for squaring a sum is $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$. (This itself follows from the distributive law applied a number of times). Set $a=k$ and $b=2$, then you get $$(k+2)^2=k^2+4k+4$$

It doesn't matter that you had $k^2+4k+4$ and are going to $(k+2)^2$, because equalities work equally well in both directions. $P=Q$ asserts that $P$ *is the same thing as* $Q$, so if you have a $Q$ you can choose to look at it as a $P$ *and vice versa*.

Answer (score 1):

$(k + 2)^2 = (k + 2)(k + 2) = k(k+ 2) + 2(k + 2) = k^2 + 2k + 2k + 4 = k^2 + 4k + 4  $

Or in general $(a + b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$.